# Form Validation in checking the number of digits entered

Tags: php, sql, html

This is my PHP file to insert data into the database.
I need to validate if the entered `pmob_number` is less than 10 digits, before storing it into the database.

```
<?php 
 $servername = "localhost";  
       $username = "root";  
       $password = "";  
       $conn = mysqli_connect ($servername , $username , $password) or  die("unable to connect to host");  
       $sql = mysqli_select_db ($conn,'vcet') or die("unable to connect to  database"); 




 //code to insert into db...
 $user_name=$_POST['user_name']; 
 $roll_number=$_POST['roll_number'];
 $user_batch=$_POST['user_batch'];
 $user_from=$_POST['user_from'];
 $user_year=$_POST['user_year'];
 $user_level=$_POST['user_level'];
 $F_name=$_POST['F_name'];
 $m_name=$_POST['m_name'];
 $g_name=$_POST['g_name'];
 $mob_number=$_POST['mob_number'];
 $addressline1=$_POST['addressline1'];
 $addressline2=$_POST['addressline2'];
 $city=$_POST['city'];
 $pmob_number=$_POST['pmob_number'];


    $msg="";

    $number_valid=$_POST['pmob_number'];

    if(strlen($number_valid)!=10){
        $msg='<span class="error">The number you enteres was not 10 digit    long</span>';

    }else
    {
        echo"valid";
    }



 $land_number=$_POST['land_number'];
 $cutoff=$_POST['cutoff'];
 $dept=$_POST['dept'];
 $medium = $_POST['medium'];
 $locality=$_POST['locality'];
 $intrest=$_POST['intrest'];
 $scholar=$_POST['scholar'];
 $income=$_POST['income'];
 $user_caste=$_POST['user_caste'];
 $user_admit=$_POST['user_admit'];
 $user_stay=$_POST['user_stay'];







 $user_info = "INSERT INTO studentinfo"." (user_name,roll_number,user_batch,user_from,user_year,user_level,F_name,m_name,g _name,mob_number,addressline1,addressline2,city,pmob_number,land_number,cutoff,d ept,medium,locality,intrest,scholar,income,user_caste,user_admit, user_stay)". "VALUES ('$user_name', '$roll_number','$user_batch','$user_from','$user_year','$user_level','$F_name','$m_name','$g_name','$mob_number','$addressline1','$addressline2','$city','$pmob_number','$land_number','$cutoff','$dept','$medium','$locality','$intrest','$scholar','$income','$user_caste','$user_admit','$user_stay')"; 
 if (!mysqli_query($conn,$user_info)) { die('Error: ' .  mysqli_error($conn)); } echo "Your information was added to the database."; 
 mysqli_close($conn); 
 ?>
```

Comment: Validation should be done in client side (javascript / jquery)

Comment: @NitinDhomse we can't always rely on client side validation, users may send POST request bypassing client side scripts.

Comment: @nitin validation should be done on the server and preferably also the client side. Never trust user input.

Comment: what specifically are you needing/wanting to know.  your use of strlen() will validate if the number is exactly 10 digits if you place that if properly it won't store the value in the database, so what are you missing or not understanding?

Comment: @Matt i trying to check the number of digits in pmob_number to be equal to 10 else error before storing the data in database

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strlen()` for server-side validation

**EDIT:** This must do the trick

```
$num_length = strlen((string)$pmob_number);
if($num_length == 10) {

     $user_info = "INSERT INTO studentinfo"." (user_name,roll_number,user_batch,user_from,user_year,user_level,F_name,m_name,g _name,mob_number,addressline1,addressline2,city,pmob_number,land_number,cutoff,d ept,medium,locality,intrest,scholar,income,user_caste,user_admit, user_stay)". "VALUES ('$user_name', '$roll_number','$user_batch','$user_from','$user_year','$user_level','$F_name','$m_name','$g_name','$mob_number','$addressline1','$addressline2','$city','$pmob_number','$land_number','$cutoff','$dept','$medium','$locality','$intrest','$scholar','$income','$user_caste','$user_admit','$user_stay')"; 
     if (!mysqli_query($conn,$user_info)) { 
        die('Error: ' .  mysqli_error($conn));
     }

     echo "Your information was added to the database."; 

    mysqli_close($conn); 

} else {
    $msg='<span class="error">The number you enteres was not 10 digit    long</span>';

}
```

Comment: he has essentially the same logic, only != instead of <=, in his code so I am guessing there is something else to his issue

Comment: I`m sorry but still it directly stores it without checking the no of digits in pmob_number

Comment: @RajCrk you should mention that in your question.

Comment: @RajCrk it directly stores it because you validate the number of digits but then outside of that validation you insert the record.  Your insert statement needs to be in your validation flow, one way of doing that is moving your insert code into the IF statement on the valid side (else)

Comment: @Matt yes i did what you said ...Then i got this error    
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\DB\info1.php on line 74